# How to implement Search Function using Singly Linked List in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Hello fellow Programmers!
I would like to ask how to implement the Search Function in Singly Linked List using Java (Data Structures).

PROBLEM: The Search function of my program can only access the head and tail of the elements.
Question: How can I access all the elements?

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyLinkedList<T> {
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;

public void add(T element){
    Node<T> nd = new Node<T>();
    nd.setValue(element);
     if(head == null){
        head = nd;
        tail = nd;
      }
     else {
        tail.setNextRef(nd);
        tail = nd;
      }}
 public void delete(){
    if(head == null){
        System.out.println("List is empty...");
    }
    else{
    Node<T> tmp = head;
    head = tmp.getNextRef();
    if(head == null){
        tail = null;
    }
    System.out.println("Deleted: "+tmp.getValue());
    System.out.println("First Employee Name Deleted!");
    }
}
public void search(){
    Node<T> tmp = head;
        if(head==null){
            System.out.println("List is empty...");
        }
        else{
        String b=""+tmp.getValue();
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an employee name to search: ");
        String search = input.nextLine();
        if(b.equals(search)){
         System.out.println("Found! "+tmp.getValue());
        }
        else if (b!=search){
            System.out.println("Not Found!");
        }
        tmp = tmp.getNextRef();
    }   }
  public void show(){
    Node<T> tmp = head;
    if(head==null){
        System.out.println("List is empty...");
    }
    else{
        while(true){
        if(tmp == null){
            break;
        }

        System.out.println(tmp.getValue());
        tmp = tmp.getNextRef();
    }}
}
public static void main(String a[]){
    MyLinkedList<String> sl = new MyLinkedList<String>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    sl.add("Garcia, Bianca Axel, 001");
    sl.add("Temprosa, Camille Ann, 002");
    sl.add("Villanueva, Von Justin, 003");
    sl.add("Rivera, Reygie, 004");
    sl.add("Dapapac, Ronnelle, 005");
    sl.add("Bati, Aubrey, 006");
    sl.add("Fiestada, Diana Rose, 007");
    sl.add("Dobalada, Jojo, 008");
    sl.add("Del Mundo, Maria Ethel, 009");
    sl.add("Alejandro, Rachelle, 010");
    System.out.print("Welcome To Singly Linked List Management for Employee Names!\n(Created by: Alex del Rosario || Source Code: Mr. John Carlo Son)\n");
    while(true){
    System.out.println("*------------------------*");
    System.out.println("*PLEASE SELECT A FUNCTION*");
    System.out.println("*1.)Add Employee Name    *");
    System.out.println("*2.)Delete Employee Name *");
    System.out.println("*3.)Show Employee List   *");
    System.out.println("*4.)Search an Employee   *");
    System.out.println("*5.)Exit the program     *");
    System.out.println("*------------------------*");
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int select = input.nextInt();
    if(select==1){
    System.out.println("**Enter an employee name with ID number**");
    System.out.println("Use this format:(Last Name),(First Name),(ID number)");
    System.out.println("(ex. del Rosario, Alex, 0001)");
    System.out.print("Input here: ");
    input.nextLine();
    String employee=input.nextLine();
    sl.add(employee);
    System.out.println("Employee: "+employee+" successfully added!");
    }
    else if(select==2){
    sl.delete();
    }
    else if(select==3){
    System.out.println("Employee List:");
    sl.show();
    }
    else if(select==4){
    sl.search();
    }
    else if(select==5){
    System.out.println("*** THANK YOU FOR USING THIS PROGRAM! :) ***");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("INVALID INPUT!");
    }

    }}
}

class Node <T> implements Comparable<T> {

    private T value;
    private Node<T> nextRef;

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Node<T> getNextRef() {
        return nextRef;
    }
    public void setNextRef(Node<T> ref) {
        this.nextRef = ref;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(T arg) {
        if(arg == this.value){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code to be easily read.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot access the following nodes? In your search a loop or something that iterates through all the elements is missing.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience sir...
I'm just new here...

Comment: Also your code appears to be a snipplet of many codes: `MyLinkedListString sl = new MyLinkedListString();` whereas your list is called `public class MyLinkedListAlex` and `class Node` versus `private NodeAlex head;`. Please post your code again when it is finished in your eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More a tipp than an answer. Ask yourself what you want to do. Do you want to use the [linked list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) provided by Java or write your own code for a linked list?

With the provided list iterating is easy.

```
private void search(String searchElement) {
     for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
         String listElement = list.get(i);
         if (searchElement.equals(listElement)) {
             System.out.println("Found element " + searchElement + " at position " + i);
             return;
         }
     }
     System.out.println(searchElement + " does not appear in the list");
}
```

When writing your own list you have to be more careful how you use the list. For example your implementation of `delete()` will not work.

```
public void delete(){
    if(head == null){
        System.out.println(List is empty...);
    }
    else{
       NodeAlex tmp = head;
       head = tmp.getNextRef();
       if(head == null){ // you need to check if head == tail or head.getNextRef() == null
          tail = null; // here you have to set tmp.setNextRef(null);
                       // and additionally define tmp as tail.
      }
      System.out.println(Deleted +tmp.getValue());
      System.out.println(First Employee Name Deleted!);
    }
}
```

Edit: To access the list you have two possibilities. At first you have to create a new instance, i.e., (here for Strings, you might want to use other types/objects)

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Then you basically have two opportunities on how to access the list in the methods.

(a) Your method is in the same class where you initialized the list, however, list has to be a global field.

```
private List<String> list;

private static void main(String[] args) {
     list = new LinkedList<String>();
     (...)
}

private static void search(String searchElement) {
     // has access on list
}
```

(b) You simply pass your list to the method you need and if the method modifies the list you need to return the list again.

```
(main class, main method)
search(list, "Test");
list = delete(list, "Test");

(the class where the methods are located)
public void search(List<String> list, String searchElement) { ... }

public List<String> delete(List<String> list, String elementToDelete) {
      // delete element
      return list;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again sir... but How can I get the given list?
From this line:
        private void search(String searchElement) {
             for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String listElement = list.get(i);

Comment: What a big help! Thanks a lot sir!